# Alerting an object() value that is gotten from an input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, object

I am trying to get an object value using the input element, but it is not   working, this is what I tried

```
    var operator = new Object();
    operator.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    operator.country = document.getElementById("country").value;
    operator.occupation = document.getElementById("occupation").value;
    operator.status = document.getElementById("status").value;
    alert(operator.name + operator.country + operator.occupation + operator.status);
```

It keeps alerting undefined.

```
       <form action="process.php" method="post" onsubmit="return myValidate()" name="myform">
```

Name:

Country:

Occupation:

Status:

Comment: what errors on console? **..but it is not working**?

Comment: not working means what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `toSource()` method which represents the source code of an object. It will return the object properties along with their values

```
alert(operator.toSource());
```

Here is an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvQTh/)

Edit:

`toSource()` does not work in Internet Explorer or Safari. It is not a good practice. So you can use

```
alert(operator.name.toString());
```

Comment: What is `.toSource()`?.Are you talking about `.toString()`

Comment: @Pilot returns the object values

Comment: @Pilot no https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource

Comment: Is `.toSource()` is meant for function object only.I am getting `uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toSource'`

Comment: `.toSource()`
**This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.***

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45348/discussion-between-pilot-and-ling-s)

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a go here http://jsfiddle.net/47LRJ/ and it works fine. can you show your HTML

```
<form>
    <input id="text" type="text" value="text" />
</form>

var obj = new Object();
obj.text =  document.getElementById("text").value;
alert(obj.text);
```

Comment: This looks similar to mine

Answer (score 0):

I guess you alert before form is filled with values (we probably need to see form html code)

Is this code called on document load?